# is there a way of using this on an air gapped windows machine?

Tags: windows, installation, download, shake-build-system

I've looked on shakebuild and it looks as though you have to have a haskell installation on a networked machine?

(verbiage to placate so follows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shake is a Haskell library for writing a build system. If you want to go for an air-gapped machine, you have three options:

1. If the build system won't change, you can compile a single static binary for your build system and ship it over to the machine. That's probably easiest. It will have no runtime dependencies.
2. If the build system changes a little bit, presumably it changes at a lower cadence than the code you are compiling. If so, just precompile the build system and ship it over with fresh code.
3. Finally, transfer enough stuff to the air gapped machine to build Haskell programs. If you are going that route, transferring enough to get the `stack` tool working is feasible - I've done it before. You are probably looking at several Gb of tools and libraries.